# How to configure maximum number of concurrent requests in Google App engine java

Tags: google-app-engine

I am designing a simple google app engine application. It simple reads data from database and returns data to client.

Since operation is very simple, I want to accept multiple requests at the same time. 
I added following entry in  appengine-web.xml

`<threadsafe>true</threadsafe>`

I am using C3P0 connection pool while querying data from database. I am facing problems in selecting correct pool size.
C3P0 connection pool size should be equal to maximum number of concurrent operations handled by GAE. 
How can I configure maximum number of concurrent operations handled by GAE?

Regards,
Sarath.

Comment: Each App Engine instance cannot have more than 12 concurrent connections to Cloud SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7927 and the docs at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/#Java_Configuration [[look for "automatic scaling"]] , you can configure the maximum number of concurrent requests per **module** -- e.g, for the default module, with:

```
  <automatic-scaling>
    <max-concurrent-requests>50</max-concurrent-requests>
  </automatic-scaling>
```

in `appengine-web.xml` -- but apparently (according to a comment on the issue tracker) the setting is not effective for front-end instances (I can't confirm the latter observation -- I would recommend you try and let us know!).